# Minecraft Version 1.7.6 crashes upon singeplayer mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have a problem that started today (5/25/2019) and it's been bugging me.

I'm trying to play on the single player game mode and re-live my old memories (version 1.7.6), as that was the time I actually really got into Minecraft (1.6.2 was when I started) and I wanted to try 1.7.6 again.

So, I opened up MC Launcher and downloaded 1.7.6... All went well until I loaded up single player and made a new world. Aaand, I crashed. So I'm going here to this website to get some help, so I hope I could get an answer.

Crash log:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Don't do that.

Time: 5/25/19 2:25 PM
Description: Unexpected error

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.get(DirectIntBufferU.java:253)
    at bok.a(SourceFile:271)
    at bok.a(SourceFile:220)
    at ban.a(SourceFile:1693)
    at ban.a(SourceFile:1651)
    at bll.a(SourceFile:118)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:70)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:13)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:166)
    at ban.p(SourceFile:1584)
    at ban.ak(SourceFile:773)
    at ban.f(SourceFile:727)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.get(DirectIntBufferU.java:253)
    at bok.a(SourceFile:271)
    at bok.a(SourceFile:220)
    at ban.a(SourceFile:1693)
    at ban.a(SourceFile:1651)
    at bll.a(SourceFile:118)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:70)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:13)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:166)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 0 total; []
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 0, 0
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (8,64,8), Chunk: (at 8,4,8 in 0,0; contains blocks 0,0,0 to 15,255,15), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 0 game time, 0 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: creative (ID 1). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 0 total; []
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Server type: Integrated singleplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at blp.a(SourceFile:289)
    at ban.b(SourceFile:1971)
    at ban.f(SourceFile:741)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.6
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 95318928 bytes (90 MB) / 234881024 bytes (224 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 13, tallocated: 95
    Launched Version: 1.7.6
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.6.0 NVIDIA 388.16, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Anisotropic filtering is supported and maximum anisotropy is 16.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.

    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: [vanilla, programer_art]
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

Comment: I can't find a bug report for this, but when people just attach the file instead of pasting it into report, I can't search for it anyway. So let's try something else: What about your setup changed since you last successfully played that version? Is it still the same computer for example?

Comment: Nope. A different computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running it in a different directory. In the profile settings, change the game directory setting to another folder, maybe on your desktop. Running two very different versions of Minecraft can corrupt save files and options. (speaking from experience here)